# Haskell -- type signature on variable or function

Tags: haskell

Here's the background, in order to build a JSON parser:

1. We have a data type `JValue` and several type constructors of that one, for example, `JNumber`, which takes one numeric value and construct a `JValue` data.

   ```
   data JValue = JNumber Double deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
   ```
2. Now we want to build a error handler which could check if the input parameter could be parsed. Here's a typeclass definition:

   ```
   type JSONError = String
   class JSON a where
       fromJValue :: JValue -> Either JSONError a
   ```
3. Then implement the instance of class JSON:

   ```
   instance JSON JValue where
       fromJValue = Right
   ```

Here's the problem, I want to try `fromJValue` with `(JNumber 1)` which should be a `JValue` type variable. However, in ghci, I have this:

```
*Main> fromJValue (JNumber 1)

<interactive>:3:1:
    No instance for (JSON a0) arising from a use of ‘it’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there is a potential instance available:
      instance JSON JValue -- Defined at JSONSubset.hs:8:10
    In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

According to this error info, it's the function `print` that can't recognize the type of return value of `fromJValue (JNumber 1)`. **That's the confusing point**: I think the result of `fromJValue` could be deduced as `Either JSONError JValue` as it's a member of `instance JSON JValue`.

**Note**: About the meaning of `fromJValue`, I think what the author tried to do is implementing the `Int` or `String` instance of `class JSON`, then we could get the content of `JValue`.

Comment: The key problem is that what you have written doesn't make any sense. What is `fromJValue` supposed to do? As it currently is, it is trying to take a `JValue` and put it in an `Either String JValue`. What is `a` in `class JSON a where` supposed to be?

Comment: @Jefffrey Thanks for your response, I've revised my question.

Comment: Look at how `aeson` implements it, you have `decode :: FromJSON a => ByteString -> Maybe a`. Whenever you use it interactively, you always have to specify it as `decode "{}" :: Maybe MyType`.  When you're using `fromJValue` in compiled code, the majority of the time those polymorphic values get converted into concrete ones at some point, so the compiler can infer what type to use, but when used interactively you have to have something that is making the type concrete before you can print it. There are exceptions to this rule, in that GHCi has defaults for `Num`, `Integral` and a few others

Comment: @bheklilr Why isn't this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `fromJSON (JValue 1)` has type `Either String a` for some type `a`, but you haven't specified what `a` is. GHC says that it knows about one particular instance, but it's not going to assume that that's the one you mean.

Here are some more examples of more possible instances of the `JSON` type class:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

-- convert to a Double
instance JSON Double where
  fromJValue (JNumber x) = Right x

-- convert to a ByteString
instance JSON B.ByteString where
  fromJValue (JNumber x) = Right (B.pack $ show x)

-- convert to an Int
instance JSON Int where
  fromJValue (JNumber x) = Left "conversion to Int not supported"
```

and some examples of using these instances:

```
ghci> let j = JNumber 123
ghci> fromJValue j :: Either String B.ByteString
Right "123.0"
ghci> fromJValue j :: Either String Double
Right 123.0
ghci> fromJValue j :: Either String Int
Left "conversion to Int not supported"
```

Without a way to infer the type of `a`, the interpretation of `fromJSON j` is ambiguous.

Comment: Hi I think that might be the point because when I tried `fromJValue (JNumber 1) :: Either JSONError JValue`, it could work. However, it's a JValue instance of class JSON so I think `a` could be replaced as `JValue`, which means the `fromJValue` function in instance JValue has type `JValue -> Either JSONError JValue`. Is that right?

Comment: `fromValue` always has the type: `JValue -> Either String a` for some type `a`, but you need to help GHC infer what `a` is. An explicit type signature (using double colons) is one way to do this. Does this help?

Comment: I see, so the signature will never be changed, right? Even if the `a` has been specified in the `instance JSON JValue`?

Comment: When you explicitly say `fromJValue ... :: Either String JValue`, then GHC knows that `a` must be `JValue`, so chooses the `instance JSON JValue` definition for `fromJValue` which is `fromJValue = Right`

Comment: Yes - `fromJValue` will always have the same polymorphic signature set forth by the `class` definition. Every new instance definition will have to follow that pattern.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, I'm wondering if you have some reference to the idea that `new instance definition will have to follow that pattern`, is that empirical?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65055/discussion-between-velvetdeth-and-user5402).

Comment: It is part of the definition of a type class - it's enforced by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>From my comment</sup>

Look at how aeson implements it, you have

```
decode :: FromJSON a => ByteString -> Maybe a
```

Whenever you use it interactively, you always have to specify it as

```
decode "{}" :: Maybe MyType
```

When you're using `fromJValue` (or `decode`) in larger projects, the majority of the time those polymorphic values get converted into concrete ones at some point, so the compiler can infer what type to use, but when used interactively you have to have something that is making the type concrete before you can print it. There are exceptions to this rule, in that GHCi has defaults for `Num`, `Integral` and a few others simply because without these defaults there would be a lot more type errors and confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm a bit confused..So you mean it's because of the execution method is **interaction** and if I compiled it there would be no problem? However, I've tried to compile it with this one: `main = putStrLn $ show (fromJValue (JNumber 1))`. But there'll be the same error..

Comment: @VELVETDETH Note that I said that in majority of cases the polymorphic values get concreted.  In your simple program here there is still nothing concreting the return value of `fromJValue`, so a type signature is still required.  This would be equivalent to `main = fmap read getLine >>= print`, this program technically type-checks, but the compiler can't make it run because it doesn't know what it's `read`ing or `show`ing, even though there are types that satisfy those constraints.

Comment: ... you'd have to have something like `main = fmap read getLine >>= (print :: Int -> IO ())` or `main = fmap (read :: String -> Int) getLine >> print`, where `Int` is now your concrete type.  In order for your type to be concreted, that type has to appear in the type signature of an expression either producing or consuming it at some point in the program.  When I say "in compiled code", I'm really referring to larger projects that are much more complex than a single line.

Comment: OK I think I've misunderstood you.. I thought `compiled code` is the one with compilation. Yeah, so the problem of concrete type will always exist until I specify it. Thanks!

Comment: @VELVETDETH I corrected my answer to remove the reference to compilation.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code compile, just change your class definition to:

```
class JSON a where
    fromJValue :: a -> Either JSONError a
```